# Access public static variable outside the class

Tags: php, oop

I have a `public` variable declared as array in class which is being used locally in class but I'm unable to use it outside the class.

below is the code

```
class permissions {
    public static $departments = array(
        "Engineering"=>array(
            'ONM','ESS','NP','NC','Engineering'
            )
        );

        // remaining code is left out for brevity

}
```

**How i can access `$department` in class declaration?**

I was expecting this way `permissions::departments;` but getting error `Undefined class constant 'departments'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use combination of scope resolution operator [`::`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) and dollar sign [`$`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073812/why-php-variables-start-with-a-sign-symbol):

```
print_r(permissions::$departments);
```

[Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: Missed a simple trcik. it worked, i can only accept answer after 9 minutes