# Reasons for dollar sign in php syntax

Tags: php

I wonder why php uses dollar sign near variables?
Is there was some technical needs? Or just for better readability (looks like worse for me)? Or that is somehow related to interpreter logic?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3073818/1012576

Comment: Of course, the "English" version of PHP doesn't use a `$`, it uses a `£` instead

Comment: ... and the Australian version uses `AU$`, which must be a right pain to type!

Comment: [English version of PHP](https://www.addedbytes.com/blog/if-php-were-british/)

Answer (score -2):

This is asked repeatedly. PHP is a on-demand parser. It needs to be very very fast. Therefore, having a $ to quickly indicate "here is a variable" makes parsing faster. Further, you *can* use a dollar sign in other languages because most consider the $ to be a valid character in variable names.

Comment: I'm not a fan of it, but I see a lot of `$` variable names in JavaScript (aside from the jQuery usage).

Comment: It's also been answered often. And never was this the accepted answer: because it's just not the reason...

Comment: If you REALLY want to get to the bottom of it, you need to talk to Ken Thompson. His goal was speed of line parsing. Using a $ made line parsing faster. That usage in the Thompson Shell continued through other shells, into Perl, and into PHP.