# Why does PHP need the use operator for closures?

Tags: php, closures

I know *what* the use operator is doing in something like `function($x,$y) use ($z) { ...`

What I don't understand is *why* PHP uses this construction when other languages don't?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why PHP variables start with a $ sign symbol?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073812/why-php-variables-start-with-a-sign-symbol)

Comment: My spontaneous tip would be that PHP's scope engine cannot efficiently deal with the problem otherwise and explicitly extending the scope of variables was simpler to implement. Again, just a guess though.

Comment: The [RFC for closures and lambdas](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/closures)  seems to get close to an answer, but appears to cover more of the _what_ than the _why_.

Comment: Because PHP is not "other languages"?!

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has rather loose variable scoping (you don't need to declare variables as global). PHP has tighter variable scoping (if a variable isn't defined within the scope that it's used, and isn't brought in with `global`, then it doesn't exist).

The `use` declaration tells PHP to make those variables available within the closure (and likely also tells the garbage collector not to clean them up until after the closure gets cleaned up).