# Use of undefined constant statement - assumed 'statement'

Tags: php, database, pdo, registration

I try to create a registration form, but there is something wrong that I can not find

class.consultas.php

```
    class consultas{
    public function nuevousuario($usuario, $pass, $email, $youtubeurl){
        $modelo = new conexion();
        $conexion = $modelo->get_conexion();
        $sql = "insert into fiver_users (user, pass, email, youtubeurl) values (:usuario, :pass, :email, :youtubeurl)";
        $statement = $conexion->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario);
        $statement->bindParam(':pass', $pass);
        $statement->bindParam(':email', $email);
        $statement->bindParam(':youtubeurl', $youtubeurl);

        if(!statement){            //Line 14 is this
            return "Error al crear el registro";
        }
        else{
            $statement->execute();
            return "Registro creado correctamente";
        }

    }
```

The error that appears to me is this:
[image: img]

Comment: `$statement`. you forgot the `$`

Comment: @Jeff, you beat me to it:
`if(!statement)` Line 14 use $statement, not statement

Comment: What's the biggest mistake I've had, Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've missed a $ in front of your statement variable.

```
    if(!statement){            //Line 14 is this
        return "Error al crear el registro";
    }
```

Should be

```
    if(!$statement){            //Line 14 is this
        return "Error al crear el registro";
    }
```

For more information about this one, check [Why PHP variables start with a $ sign symbol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3073812/why-php-variables-start-with-a-sign-symbol)

Comment: This is a simple typo and should be closed as such. No answer need be given.